# Wordpress - Creating multiple versions of the same single-customtype.php depending on selected taxonomy categories

Tags: taxonomy, custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have registered a custom post type 'Clients' and a taxonomy for this post type for categorizing posts.  There are currently 3 categories for a Client: 'Logo Project', 'Video Project' and 'Web Design' project.

Some Clients may belong to multiple categories.

On the Edit Page for a Clients post, I have a Flexible field layout builder that let's you generate 'blocks' of content for each category type (logo, web, video...).  Each block will have unique fields relevant to each category (video upload tools for video, image galleries for logo etc..)

My issue is, that while I can display relevant content on taxonomy category pages (only show web-design for all Clients that are in the web design category...), once the user clicks to view this Client, the single-clients.php page has no way of ONLY displaying Web Design content and filtering out other 'Content blocks' in cases where a Client has > 1 content block.

Ideally I need multiple versions of the clients single template:

something like:

```
1) single-clients-web.php
2) single-clients-logo.php
3) single-clients-video.php
4) single-clients.php (shows all project blocks as it does now)
```

OR

somehow take a referral ID and write a conditional that if the user clicked on the client from the web design category page, the single page they are directed to only shows the web design fields.

Comment: Will each client be assigned to only one category?

Comment: No.  Some clients might be placed into multiple categories.  For example, if Logo, Web and Video services were provided for this client, they would be placed into all 3 of those categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the following code should do the trick for you:

```
function get_clients_correct_template($single_template) {
    global $post;

    if ( 'clients' == $post->post_type ) {
        $_template = false;
        // Get all the terms for this post
        $categories = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'clients_categories' );
        if ( $categories && ! is_wp_error( $categories ) ) {
            global $wp;
            // I guessed that the client category that's in the URL will be in the query, but it's not, so we have to get it from $wp->matched_query
            if ( preg_match( '~clients_categories=[\w|\d|-]*&?~', $wp->matched_query ) ) {
                $slug = preg_replace( '~.*?clients_categories=([\w|\d|-]*)&?.*?$~', '\1', $wp->matched_query );
                // See if the slug we found matches a slug of one of the client's categories
                foreach ( $categories as $cat ) {
                    if ( $cat->slug == $slug ) {
                        $_template = locate_template( array( "single-clients-{$slug}.php" ), false );
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // If we haven't found a template yet, just assign the first found template
            if ( ! $_template ) {
                $_template = locate_template( array( "single-clients-{$categories[0]->slug}.php" ), false );
            }
            $single_template = $_template ? $_template : $single_template;
        }
    }

    return $single_template;
}
// This is pre WP 3.4
add_filter( "single_template", "get_clients_correct_template", 1000 );
// This is post WP 3.4
add_filter( "clients_template", "get_clients_correct_template", 1000 );

// Fixes the permalinks for the "clients" post type
function clients_custom_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    if ( strpos( $permalink, 'client/' ) === FALSE || ! ( $post = get_post( $post_id ) ) || get_post_type( $post_id ) != 'clients' ) {
        return $permalink;
    }

    // Get taxonomy terms
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'clients_categories' );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) && ! empty( $terms ) && is_object( $terms[0] ) ) {
        $taxonomy_slug = false;
        if ( is_tax( 'clients_categories' ) ) {
            $term = get_queried_object();
            $taxonomy_slug = $term->slug;
        } else {
            $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
        }
    } else {
        $taxonomy_slug = 'no-category';
    }
    $replace_count = 1;

    return preg_replace( '~client/~', $taxonomy_slug . '/', $permalink, $replace_count );
}
add_filter('post_link', 'clients_custom_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'clients_custom_permalink', 10, 3);

// Fixes the URL's for taxonomy archives
function clients_categories_custom_permalink($permalink, $term, $taxonomy) {
    if ( $taxonomy != 'clients_categories' ) {
        return $permalink;
    }

    return home_url( "/{$term->slug}/" );
}
add_filter( 'term_link', 'clients_categories_custom_permalink', 10, 3 );

// Generates custom rewrite rules for recognizing the custom Permalink structure for both "clients" posts and "clients_categories" terms
function add_client_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    static $did_rules = false;
    if ( ! $did_rules ) {
        $additional_rules = array();
        $terms = get_terms( 'clients_categories', array( 'hide_empty' => false ) );
        if ( $terms ) {
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                // Add a rule for the taxonomy archives of the type "client-category-slug[/]" - the "/" is optional
                $additional_rules[ "({$term->slug})/?$" ] = 'index.php?clients_categories=$matches[1]';
                // Add a rule of the sort "client-category-slug/client-slug"
                $additional_rules[ "({$term->slug})/([^/]*)" ] = 'index.php?clients_categories=$matches[1]&clients=$matches[2]';
                // Add a rule of the sort "client-category-slug/parent-client-slug/client-slug"
                $additional_rules[ "({$term->slug})/([^/]*)/([^/]*)" ] = 'index.php?clients_categories=$matches[1]&clients=$matches[3]';
            }
            $wp_rewrite->rules = array_merge( $additional_rules, $wp_rewrite->rules );
        }
        $did_rules = true;
    }
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_client_rewrite_rules' );
```

As for a begining, I assumed that the slug of your custom post type is `clients` and the slug of your custom taxonomy is `clients_cateogires` - if any of those are incorrect, please find and replace those occurances in my code.

In the arguments for `register_post_type()` for your `clients` post type, you have to set `rewrite` to:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'clients', 'with_front' => false ),
```

Also in the arguments for `register_taxonomy()` you have to set `rewrite` to(any other slug will work as well):

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'client-category', 'with_front' => false ),
```

So, the first function hooks to the `single_template` and `clients_template` filter hooks. You can read in detail about this hook [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template), but basically this hook allows you to change the template that is being loaded when a singular(page, post, custom post type post) post is being displayed. We hook to this function, so that we can load the appropriate template when a clients post is being loaded.

First we check that the post type of the current post is actually the target one(`clients`).

Then we get all categories associated with the current client. If there are no categories, we let WordPress load the default template.

If there are categories we first check to see if the queried URL contains a `clients_categories` slug. Initially I thought that WP would add the slug of the `clients_categories` that is part of the URL, but it seems that it doesn't. Instead I found that in the `$matched_query` property of the `$wp` object. If it matches a simple regular expression, we extract the slug and check it against the slugs of the categories that the current `client` is associated with. If one of them matches, we try to find a template `single-clients-{$slug}.php`.

If we couldn't find the searched term, or the proper template for this term, we get the first category for this client and try to find the template for it(using it's slug).

In the end if we have found an appropriate template, we set the `$single_template` variable to it, otherwise we preserver it's original value.

---

Now the second part replaces `client/` from the clients permalink with the appropriate `clients_categories` slug for this client. Note that it also checks to see if we're on a term from the `clients_categories` taxonomy - if we are, it will use the slug of the current term. Otherwise it will add the slug of the first term that it finds.

---

The third part(`clients_categories_custom_permalink()`) fixes the URL's for the taxonomy archives - this way the "Web" category will be at `http://example.com/web/`.

---

The fourth part(`add_client_rewrite_rules()`) adds some custom rewrite rules - **note, that for these to take effect, you have to go to `Settings > Permalinks`** - so that WordPress knows what it should display when it encounters an URL like `http://example.com/web/` or `http://example.com/web/client-slug/`.

---

**Note that if you have a page with a slug that matches one of the slugs for your Clients Categories - you will most-likely see the taxonomy archive, instead of the page.**

Comment: Wow man this looks great and looks like it was a lot of work.  Much appreciated.

I tested the code but I am getting a global error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'break' (T_BREAK) in

Comment: I'm also concerned too that although we have unique templates, each of the pages need to be indexed somehow...we can't just have an ever-changing single page that changes depending on where the user is coming from.  If a post belongs to all 3 of the categories, there needs to be 3 total versions of that post, all indexable.  So:

domain.com/tax-category-webdesign/client-name/
domain.com/tax-category-logodesign/client-name

Comment: About the error - it's the most common one for me - I was missing a `;` on the line before `break;`. That's a proper concern, but wouldn't it be better if you simply have 3 clients for each category, instead of one for all 3? I mean it will be 1) easier and 2) each client will have it's unique URL. Although if you can make the different URL's link to the same client(so basically whatever term slug you use, it will end-up to the same client), then we might be able to make that work.

Comment: If we don't use this method, administrator will need to create multiple posts for one client such as:

Client Logo
Client Web
Client Video

Which will result in a lot of unorganized content.  It'd be much easier to create one post on client, and when editing this post, be able to input content for each category - logo, web, video.

Comment: I tried the code but it doesn't seem to be working.  Do I have to query anything specific on the taxonomy category pages to tie into this function?

Comment: Hi Alex, I've updated my answer. I've tested the code and it should work for you this time. Just adjust the `client` and `clients_categories` to whatever slugs you're using for your custom post type and custom taxonomy. If you get a 404 error, update your permalinks and try again. Hope it helps :)]

Comment: What should the permalink structure be?  I am just using 'post-name'?

Comment: I got it working, except for the templates.  Wow this is cool man...just now have to get the templates working

Comment: Can you do `var_dump( $wp->matched_query );` just after `global $wp;` and tell me what it says?

Comment: doesn't echo out anything for me - i am viewing a client

Comment: Hmmm, can you try doing some test `echo`'s? Like before `if ( 'clients' == $post->post_type )` and then before `if ( $categories && ! is_wp_error( $categories ) )`? To see where we're not getting to the point :)

Comment: hmm weird if i echo anywhere in the function get_clients_correct_template($single_template) i don't see anything on the front end...

Comment: Pretty weird... You have the proper `add_filter` function calls, right? Can you set `WP_DEBUG` to true?

Comment: Yes, i'm using add_filter( "clients_template", "get_clients_correct_template", 1000 );
turning on WP_DEBUG displays nothing :(

Comment: Can you try also adding `add_filter( "single_template", "get_clients_correct_template", 1000 );`? It seems that either the filter hook is not firing. If it was a problem with the function name, it should have given a warning when you turned on WP_DEBUG. Also this code is in the same file where the `clients_custom_permalink()` function is, right?

Comment: ok that looks like it did something - the templates are being picked up.  var_dump( $wp->matched_query ); spits out: string 'clients_categories=logo-design&clients=this-is-test&page=' when viewing a client on logo-design taxonomy.  there is a different problem which is one client is part of two taxonomies, both logo and web design.  if you view the project from category page for logo design it spits out my unique code for logo, but if u click on web design it's still showing the logo-design template...

Comment: Is the URL for the client changing when you're on the web design category? Also what does `var_dump( preg_match( '~clients_categories=\w*&?~', $wp->matched_query ) );` say?

Comment: Yes, URL changes.  I am on /web-design/project-name but for some reason its showing this project's logo template (project is under both web and logo taxes).  It says 'int 1'.  ALso, when I view a project that is ONLY a part of /web-design/, it's showing the correct template.

Comment: Okay, so add `var_dump( $slug );` just after the `$slug = preg_replace(...` line. Then add `var_dump( $cat->slug );` just after `foreach ( $categories as $cat )`. This is the part where our function is failing

Comment: string 'web' (length=3)
string 'web-design' (length=10)...when viewing a client that i have placed in 3 taxonomy cats, it spits out: string 'web' (length=3)
string 'logo-design' (length=11)
string 'video-production' (length=16)
string 'web-design' (length=10) (when viewing web-design version)...so it seems to list them in order somehow, logo-design being first defaults to the logo-design template..?

Comment: Oooooh... I see where the problem is :) The regular expression looks for `clients_categories=\w*&?` which more or less means "look for `clients_categories=` followed by any length of alphabetical characters, until you reach a `&` sign". I'll update my answer with the proper regular expression, that will allow digits and dashes in the slug.

Comment: I saw you updated.  I can confirm that everything works now :)